# `$this->getViewFileUrl` adding en_us to a url

Tags: magento2, template, image, helper

I'm trying to add an image from my theme in template like

`<img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('Vendor_Theme::images/image.svg'); ?>" />`

But this url adds en_us. How can I remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normal behavior.

During [deployment static content](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html) all files from directories like `Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web` will be copied to `[MAGENTO_ROOT]/pub/static/....`.

After that static content will be available for loading by client side (your browser for example).

Comment: How do I fix it? Cause now image can't be found because of that.

Comment: try to rerun static content deploy

Comment: I've done it a few times, but nothing changes. I also tried `<img src="{{images/image.svg}}" />`, but it also doesn't work. I'm trying to show an image that is in the theme. I'm rewriting one template (I'm doing it in the theme itself).

Comment: for example `app/code/Magento/Captcha/view/adminhtml/templates/default.phtml` contains code `<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getViewFileUrl('Magento_Captcha::reload.png')) ?>` and look like works. try to validate your image location according example

Comment: I just needed to remove `Vendor_Theme` and it started to work. Thanks.